# Regexp: распарсить строку

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, синтаксический-анализ

Здравствуйте. Помогите распарсить срочку с такой грамматикой:

```
<expression> = ‘=’ <term> { <operation> <term> }
<term> = <cell reference> | <non-negative number> 
<cell reference > = <letter> <digit> 
<operation> = ‘+’ | ‘-‘ | ‘*’ | ‘/’
<text> = ‘’’{<printable character>}
```

Comment: Напиши пример того, что есть и что нужно. не совсем из этого понятно. В частности не понятна последняя строка.

Comment: Это что то типо табличного процессора. 
Должна быть строка вида "=А1+B2-2+5".
Мне нужно ссылки на ячейки (А1, В2) заменить значениями из этих ячеек.
Так же может быть строка вида "’какойто текст". Тут просто нужно вытянуть текст.

Comment: в общем случае, не очень рекомендуется использовать регулярные выражения, если есть возможность использовать стандартные строковые методы, т.к. они будут работать по-шустрее

Comment: Что Вы хотите увидеть в результате на строку:  

    = а1 + б1 + в1
1) Результат это строка:  

    = 5 + 6 + 7
где цифры это значения ячеек.  
2) Результат это число:  

    18

Comment: @ReinRaus: Я думаю, результатом должно быть parse tree:

    <expression>
        =
        <cellreference>
            <letter> а
            <digit> 1
        <operation> +
        <cellreference>
            <letter> б
            <digit> 1
        <operation> +
        <cellreference>
            <letter> в
            <digit> 1

Comment: @VladD, как-то сложно. Регулярками все проще намного :-)

Comment: А мен казалось, наоборот, просто. Имея синтаксическое дерево, вы можете сделать что угодно: сложить, напечатать красиво, сериализовать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы отсеить строки, может подойдёт

```
re.compile('^(\w|\s)*$')
```

Сюда не попадёт начальное "=".

Под проверку второго (вашего выражения) может подойти, но смотрите от своего случая:

```
re.compile('^(\w|(\+|-|/|\*|=))+$')
```

получить имена ячеек можете (выдастся список):

```
re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]\d+', string)
```

А потом можете, например пробежаться по этому списку и заменить адреса ячеек на значения:

```
string.replace(cell_reference, cell_value)
```

Comment: во второй регулярке лучше = вынести вперёд. В формулах оно ведь один раз только. Но это я не знаю точно.

Answer (score 4):

Раз уж у вас уже есть готовая грамматика, почему бы и не взять для этого один из генераторов лексических парсеров/токенайзеров, коих много?

Comment: да, кстати, для питончика вроде есть какие-то толковые модули для работы с натуральными языками, но сам с такими тасками не сталкивался, так что ничего конкретного посоветовать не могу